# 3D sphere vs sphere collision resolve problem

Tags: c++, physics, collision

I have been watching [OneLoneCoder video about circle collision resolve](https://youtu.be/LPzyNOHY3A4)
 and use the [code from git](https://github.com/OneLoneCoder/videos/blob/master/OneLoneCoder_Balls1.cpp).

But the code is for 2D case, i.e. circles, and I need a solution for spheres. So I tried to add Z-component to equations but getting failures.

So I am testing the next way: I create two spheres, one above other. Lower is situated a heavy sphere, upper a tiny. The higher sphere is falling. In reality tiny should bounce up, but it just stuck, and they are falling as a single body for a while, but then the higher sphere is bouncing up. Also the sphere per each jump gets higher(see gif):

[image]

Here is the code:

```
/*
vertex - VERTEX **vertex=new VERTEX*[100];
vc - vertex count (how many vertices are currently created)
*/

void Update()
{
auto DoCirclesOverlap = [](float x1, float y1, float z1, float r1, float x2, float y2, float z2, float r2)
 {
  return ((x1 - x2)*(x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2)*(y1 - y2) + (z1 - z2)*(z1 - z2)) <= (r1 + r2)*(r1 + r2);
 };
 vector<pair<VERTEX*, VERTEX*>> vecCollidingPairs;
 // Update vertex[i] Positions
 for (int i = 0;i < vc;i++)
 {
  // Update vertex[i] physics
  
  vertex[i]->x += vertex[i]->vx * TIME_QUANT_CONSTANT;
  vertex[i]->y += vertex[i]->vy * TIME_QUANT_CONSTANT;
  vertex[i]->z += vertex[i]->vz * TIME_QUANT_CONSTANT;
 }
 // Static collisions, i.e. overlap
 
 for (int i(0);i < vc;i++)
 {
  
  for(int j(0);j < vc;j++)
  {
   if (vertex[i]->index != vertex[j]->index)
   {
    if (DoCirclesOverlap(vertex[i]->x, vertex[i]->y, vertex[i]->z, vertex[i]->size, vertex[j]->x, vertex[j]->y, vertex[j]->z, vertex[j]->size))
    {
     // Collision has occured
     vecCollidingPairs.push_back({ vertex[i], vertex[j] });
     
      // Distance between vertex[i] centers
      float fDistance = sqrtf((vertex[i]->x - vertex[j]->x)*(vertex[i]->x - vertex[j]->x) + (vertex[i]->y - vertex[j]->y)*(vertex[i]->y - vertex[j]->y) + (vertex[i]->y - vertex[j]->y)*(vertex[i]->y - vertex[j]->y));
      // Calculate displacement required
      float fOverlap = 0.5f * (fDistance - vertex[i]->size - vertex[j]->size);
      // Displace Current vertex[i] away from collision
      
      
       vertex[i]->x -= fOverlap * (vertex[i]->x - vertex[j]->x) / fDistance;
       vertex[i]->y -= fOverlap * (vertex[i]->y - vertex[j]->y) / fDistance;
       vertex[i]->z -= fOverlap * (vertex[i]->z - vertex[j]->z) / fDistance;
       // Displace vertex[j] vertex[i] away from collision
       vertex[j]->x += fOverlap * (vertex[i]->x - vertex[j]->x) / fDistance;
       vertex[j]->y += fOverlap * (vertex[i]->y - vertex[j]->y) / fDistance;
       vertex[j]->z += fOverlap * (vertex[i]->z - vertex[j]->z) / fDistance;
      
     
    }
   }
  }
 }
 // Now work out dynamic collisions
 for (auto c : vecCollidingPairs)
 {
  VERTEX *b1 = c.first;
  VERTEX *b2 = c.second;
  // Distance between vertex[i]s
  float fDistance = sqrtf((b1->x - b2->x)*(b1->x - b2->x) + (b1->y - b2->y)*(b1->y - b2->y) + (b1->z - b2->z)*(b1->z - b2->z));
  // Normal
  float nx = (b2->x - b1->x) / fDistance;
  float ny = (b2->y - b1->y) / fDistance;
  float nz = (b2->z - b1->z) / fDistance;
  // Tangent
  float tx = -ny;
  float ty = nx;
  float tz = nz;
  // Dot Product Tangent
  float dpTan1 = b1->vx * tx + b1->vy * ty + b1->vz * tz;
  float dpTan2 = b2->vx * tx + b2->vy * ty + b2->vz * tz;
  // Dot Product Normal
  float dpNorm1 = b1->vx * nx + b1->vy * ny + b1->vz * nz;
  float dpNorm2 = b2->vx * nx + b2->vy * ny + b2->vz * nz;
  // Conservation of momentum in 1D
  float m1 = (dpNorm1 * (b1->mass - b2->mass) + 2.0f * b2->mass * dpNorm2) / (b1->mass + b2->mass);
  float m2 = (dpNorm2 * (b2->mass - b1->mass) + 2.0f * b1->mass * dpNorm1) / (b1->mass + b2->mass);
  // Update ball velocities
  b1->vx = tx * dpTan1 + nx * m1;
  b1->vy = ty * dpTan1 + ny * m1;
  b1->vz = tz * dpTan1 + nz * m1;
  b2->vx = tx * dpTan2 + nx * m2;
  b2->vy = ty * dpTan2 + ny * m2;
  b2->vz = tz * dpTan2 + nz * m2;
 }
 }
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Have you considered using vector data structures instead of processing the vector components manually? It would really be more intuitive to look at and would have prevented the distance calculation from being wrong in the first place. There's lots of libraries for this too, such as glm.

Comment: @Chris actually I tried a lot of. Almost all of time I used `Vector3` from Directx (because I am using it). But the code I copied is currently the best solution. I just haven’t changed it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Tyyppi_77 from Stack GameDev, where I posted the same [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/184621/138126), that pointed that the issue was on line

```
float fDistance = sqrtf((vertex[i]->x - vertex[j]->x)*(vertex[i]->x - vertex[j]->x) + (vertex[i]->y - vertex[j]->y)*(vertex[i]->y - vertex[j]->y) + (vertex[i]->y - vertex[j]->y)*(vertex[i]->y - vertex[j]->y));
```

And the correct one is

```
float fDistance = sqrtf((vertex[i]->x - vertex[j]->x)*(vertex[i]->x - vertex[j]->x) + (vertex[i]->y - vertex[j]->y)*(vertex[i]->y - vertex[j]->y) + (vertex[i]->z - vertex[j]->z)*(vertex[i]->z - vertex[j]->z));
```

It just solved almost all of issues. The only terrible thing is, because of static collision, the lower and **much more** heavier sphere is a little bit shifts down while it is hit by the sphere above. Do You know how it can be solved?

Comment: It sounds like the issue is due to the larger sphere thinking it's being hit a lot harder than it actually is due to the intersection of the first sphere (which may also be related to the framerate). If you calculate the collision based on _when_ the collision occurs instead of _if_ a collision occurs, you can easily calculate the positions and velocities of each sphere at the point of impact which should result in a more accurate update to their velocities.

Comment: @Chris will try this tomorrow